# Epsilon-delta proofs

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

$\newcommand{\absval}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$

I am self-learning `Real Analysis` from Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abott. I am getting back to $\delta-\epsilon$ arguments after a break, so I'd like ask if my $\delta$-response to the below $\epsilon$-challenges is technically correct and rigorous.

> Problem 4.2.2. For each stated limit, find the largest possible $\delta-$neighbourhood that is a proper response to the given $\epsilon$-challenge.

> (a) $\lim_{x \to 3}(5x - 6) = 9$, where $\epsilon = 1$

> (b) $\lim_{x \to 4}\sqrt{x} = 2$, where $\epsilon = 1$

> (c) $\lim_{x \to \pi} [[x]] = 3$, where $\epsilon = 1$. (The function $[[x]]$ returns the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$)

> (d) $\lim_{x \to \pi} [[x]] = 3$, where $\epsilon = 0.01$

***Proof.***

(a) We would like to make the distance $\absval{(5x - 6) - 9}<1$, so $\absval{5x - 15} < 1$, thus $\absval{x - 3} < 1/5$. Thus, $\delta = 1/5$.

(b) The expression $\absval{\sqrt{x} - 2}$ can be written as,

\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{x} - 2 &= (\sqrt{x} - 2) \times \frac{(\sqrt{x} + 2)}{(\sqrt{x} + 2)}\\
 &= \frac{\absval{(x - 4)}}{\absval{\sqrt{x} + 2}}\\
 &\le \frac{\absval{(x - 4)}}{2}\\
 &< \frac{\delta}{2}
\end{align*}

So, if we pick $\delta = 2$, the distance $\absval{\sqrt{x} - 2}$ would be smaller than $\epsilon = 1$.

(c) Consider the expression $\absval{[[x]] - 3}$.

We are interested to make the distance $\absval{[[x]] - 3}$ smaller than $\epsilon = 1$. So, $2 < [[x]] < 4$. Therefore, $[[x]]=3$. This is true, if and only if, $3 \le x < 4$. Consequently, $3 - \pi \le x - \pi < 4 - \pi$. This inequality is satisfied, if the distance $\absval{x - \pi} < \pi - 3$. So, $\delta = \pi - 3$.

(d) Again, $\delta = \pi - 3$ is a proper response to the given $\epsilon-$ challenge.

Comment: Good job! Notice only that $\delta = 2$ "works", but it's not the largest possible value. This is because you used an inequality. In fact, what you wrote would be the best way to establish this limit, as usually one doesn't care about finding the optimal $\delta$.

Comment: I wonder what's the point of finding largest possible $\delta$? This is so so against the spirit of definition of limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all good except part (b), which is wrong because you are requested to find the largest $\delta$, which must be $(\delta = 3)$, since
$|\sqrt{4-3} - 2| = 1.$